# How to show user not found error using node.js and mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest

I am implementing registration API, in this registration, I have email as unique and I want to check if email exists or not in db if exists it has to show email already exists message else it has to register.everything works fine up to this.Now I want to check if an email does not exist in the database it has to show user not found the error but I am not able to display this message.

Here is my code

```
createUser: function(req, res, next) {
UserModel.getByEmail(req.body.email,function(err, user) {
    if(err) {
        res.json({ 'valid': false, 'message': err.message });
    } else {
        if(!user) {
            res.json({ 'valid': false, 'message': 'User not exists'}); //this message is not showing
        } else {
            if(user[0].id) {
                console.log('hi');
                res.json({ 'valid': false, 'message': 'Email already exists'});//works only if i use user[0].id instead of user
            } else {        
                UserModel.addUser(req, token, function(err, data) {
                    //console.log(data);
                    if (err) {
                        res.json({ 'valid': false, 'message': err.message });
                    } else {
                        console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
                        res.json({Error: info.response});
                        res.json({ 'valid': true, 'message': 'User added succesfully', req:req.body, data : data  });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
});},
```

In getByEmail method

```
getByEmail: function(email, rows){
var sql = "SELECT * FROM sbt_users WHERE email = ?";
var fields = [email];
return db.query(sql, fields, rows);}
```

if(!user) is not working.Can anyone explain how to show that message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user` is an array of records. If the array is empty, it's length will be 0.

So you can check `if (user.length === 0)`

Comment: it worked for me thank you but i got another error when i send request for user, it is inserted in db again requesting another user it is showing throw new errors.Error('ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT', 'set');
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: Open a new stack overflow question!